# Why $\phi(t) \leq L\int_{0}^{t}\phi (s) ds$ for all $t$ and $\phi \geq 0$ implies $\phi=0$?

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

I have problems understanding the last part of the proof of uniqueness of solutions in Cauchy-Lipshitz theorem, in the book of Haïm Brezis (functional analysis, sobolev spaces and PDEs, page 185).

He states that since
$$ \phi (t) \leq L \int_{0}^{t} \phi(s)ds$$
for all $t\geq 0$, where $L>0$ and $\phi \geq 0$, then we have $\phi = 0$ and therefore uniqueness (since $\phi$ is just the norm of the difference between two possible solutions). How to prove this, why $\phi$ should necessarily be equal to zero here ?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$ of the PDE (4) stated in Proposition 7.3 page 184. As these two functions are solution, we have $u_i \in C^1([0,\infty), E)$ (for $E$ a Banach space) and
$$u_i(t) = u_0 + \int_0^t F(u_i(s)) ds$$
for a Lipschitz function $F$ with constant $L$ (see (5) page 184). Now we define $ \phi(t) = \|u_1(t) - u_2(t)\|$ and we have
$$\phi(t) = \left\|\int_0^t F(u_1(s)) - F(u_2(s))ds\right\| \le \int_0^t \left\|F(u_1(s)) - F(u_2(s))\right\|ds \le L\int_0^t \phi(s)ds.$$

**EDIT:** To prove that $\phi = 0$ just apply [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality).

Comment: Thank you, but this part I understood it. My problem is how from $\phi \leq L\int \phi$ he deduces that $\phi =0$.

Comment: Oh my bad, I misread the question.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand it now.